How can I calculate $\chi(\mathscr{O}(P))$
Let be X a reduced and irreducible curve over a field $L_0$. Let $L$ an extension of $L_0$ and set
\begin{gather*}
\overline{X}=L \otimes X.
\end{gather*}
Assume $\overline{X}$ also irreducible. Now, let $P_0 \in X$ be a regular closed point and set $P=L \otimes P_0$. If $\mathscr{O}_{\overline{X}}(P)$ is the ideal sheaf of $P$, how can I calculate $\chi(\mathscr{O}_{\overline{X}}(P))$? I do not really know much of sheaf cohomology, so any comment will be really helpful to me.
Thanks!

That is only well defined if $X$ is proper.  In that case, it equals $\chi(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ minus the degree of the field extension of the residue field of $P$ over $L_0$.

To clarify how to derive the result given in Jason Starr's comment, write down the additivity of $\chi$ for the short exact sequence $0 \to \mathcal{O}{\bar X}(P) \to \mathcal{O}{\bar X} \to \mathcal{O}_P \to 0$ and $\mathcal{O}_P$ is a skyscraper sheaf.

By the way, the standard notation is $\mathscr{O}_{\bar{X}}(-P)$.
